Using bernoulli's equation in a siphon doesn't work out?
I was thinking about doing a simple siphon experiment for my physics project like the follwing image:

The problem is, I can't calculate the flow rate of water in this situation - I used bernoulli's equation to get
$$P_A + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_A^2 =P_B + \frac{1}{2} \rho v_B^2$$
and the continuity equation to get
$$A_A v_A = A_B v_B$$
($v_A = v_B$ if the cross-section of the tube is constant)
But I don't know how to get $P_A$ and $P_B$ : I set $P_A = P_0 +\rho g h_1$ and $P_B = P_0 +\rho g h_2$ since the water in the cups is almost not moving, but this led to no solutions if $v_A = v_B$. What should I do to calculate the correct flow rate?
Added : The height of two ends are the same, so the height difference of the two surfaces is $h_1-h_2$

Oh I forgot to mention that the height of two ends are the same, so the height difference of the two surfaces is $h_1-h_2$. I'll add it in the question too, thanks.

In steady flow  with constant $h_1-h_2$ the  flow speed  in the siphon is determined the fluid viscosity and diameter of the pipes. Viscosity means that   Bernoulli does not apply. In the  the absence of viscosity, the flow will not be steady because fluid speed will be increasing due to the pressure difference between A and B, so  even then you need to add the $\partial \phi/\partial t$ term to your Bernoulli equations.

Thanks! So this case needs to be dealt with unsteady bernoulli equation, right?

@ fugue Yes. Exactly so. In the irrotational case where  we can write ${\bf v}= \nabla \phi$, you just add a $\partial \phi/\partial t$ to the ${\bf v}^2/2+P/\rho$
